# Find file in directories of PATH env which match partially

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

Idea is to match a filename in any of directories mentioned in PATH environment. Usually, we do this by running "which <executable_filename>".

This works fine, when the file your are searching matches exactly in any of directories in PATH. If file contains a "suffix", this would fail. Is there a way to circumvent this?

which should work for "<executable_filename>-linux" where we now have a suffix of "-linux". Is there any other tool to match above, when searching only filename without suffix? or can it done using which?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the work:

- `compgen -c | grep 'YOUR_SEARCH_STRING'`

Example:

- `compgen -c | grep '\-linux'`

---

Hope that helped :)